# Efficient use of Octave's randsample (with weights) in a situation of huge vector and most weights equal to zero

Tags: random, octave

In an upcoming simulation project, I will come in a situation where I will have to draw one random element from a huge vector in a weighted sense. For most elements of the vector, the assigned weight will be zero. I also need to draw only one element, so the replacement or no replacement function is irrelevant.

This random picking step will be the bottleneck for my simulation, so getting the best efficiency and speed will be critical.

Are there any hacks/tips on what is best to do? Are there any important savings possible in the context of my project?

PS: Is randsample reliable on huge vectors?

Comment: You draw one element per sample or per vector? How often you alter/change vector?

Comment: Basically, there is fast O(1) alias sampling for discrete values, but it requires setup, so if you change vector often, might not worth it. https://possiblywrong.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/the-alias-method-and-double-precision/

Comment: I will have to change vector several times (although the change to the vector upon each iteration is O(1)). I read the wikipedia page on the alias method and in its final paragraph it is mentioned that it doesn't work very well for "unbalanced" probabilities though.

Comment: Well, the only other possibility I could think about is to sort vector according to probabilities and sample only from top non-zero part

Comment: Is the weight vector is constant?

Comment: No, like I said: most entries are zero, with some exceptions being non-zero (the number of non-zeroes still scales to infinity along with the size of the vector though. The position of the non-zeroes also changes during iterations of the algorithm)

Comment: “This random picking step will be the bottleneck for my simulation” you don’t know this until you implement the simulation and profile. Please don’t make assumptions about what is expensive or not, humans are notoriously bad at guessing algorithm performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that most weights are equal to zero you can rewrite a faster implementation of `randsample` from Octave source. In my timing it is `6X-7X` faster than the original implementation:

```
function y = randsample_fast(v, w)
    f = find(w);
    w = w(f);
    w = w / sum(w);
    w = [0 cumsum(w)];
    y = f(lookup (w , rand));
    %y = f(find (w <= rand, 1, "last"));
    y = v(y);
end
```

- Inputs are assumed to be row vectors.
- Changing `find` to `lookup` may slightly improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the source code of `randsample.m` in the statistics package. It's actually quite a simple implementation. It creates a normalised cumulative weights vector from the weights vector, and then effectively samples it via standard inverse sampling.

I don't know what you mean by 'huge', but as long as the weights vector can fit in memory, there is no reason why this shouldn't be fast.

If by 'huge' you mean something that does not fit in memory, then you could create a 'huge version' of this function that splits the cumulative weights vector into predictable 'bins' saved on disk, and only performs inverse sampling from the right bin.

The only thing I'd add to this is, given the implementation and that you're only interested in a single draw, then you would probably benefit from speed if you specified 'replacement' as 'true' explicitly, since the default is 'false' (i.e. *without* replacement), and sampling *with* replacement seems to avoid a lot of unnecessary and expensive steps (permutations etc).